# Story source: rabbi sweeping streets, take pride in your work?

Tags: rabbis, story-identification, hasidic-story

I once heard a story that when a European gadol first came to America he had to take a job as a street sweeper and "nobody ever swept the streets as well as he did." The message of the story seemed to be that whatever you have to do you should do it well and take pride in it. The version I heard was ostensibly about Rav Moshe Feinstein, but I don't think that is plausible because when he came to America I think he went straight into rabanut. Does anyone have a source or more details about this story?

I am not talking about the story of the [Sadigura Rebbe sweeping the streets in Israel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avrohom_Yaakov_Friedman_(third_Sadigura_rebbe)#:%7E:text=The%20Sadigura%20Rebbe%20was%20seized,gladly%20sweep%20the%20streets%20there.).

Comment: Rav Moshe said he would rather be a street-sweeper in the US where he had religious freedom to teach his children Torah, than be the Greatest Rabbi in the Soviet Union and prohibited from doing so. That's all I've heard about him and street-sweeping.